# Why isn't the right font color set in the smart table?

Tags: excel, vba

I use Tables on a sheet.
I check the box "Hide price" and run the associated code. The code hides the values ​​in the target cells, setting the font color in them to the fill color.
When you click the check mark again, the code starts again and sets the font color in the cell the same as in the exemplary cell on the left.
Since Tables are used, the user can choose some express style in which the font color in the cells can be different. Therefore, I can not set any particular color, for example, black.

```
With Sheets("Calculation")
    For r = 9 To 10
    For c = 22 To 23
        .Cells(r, c).Select
        clr1 = .Cells(r, c).DisplayFormat.Interior.ColorIndex
        clr2 = .Cells(r, c).DisplayFormat.Font.ColorIndex
        'colorindex of exemplary cell
        .Cells(r, 21).Select
        clr3 = .Cells(r, 20).DisplayFormat.Font.ColorIndex
        v = .Cells(2, 25).Value
        If .Cells(2, 25).Value = True Then
            If clr1 > 0 Then
                .Cells(r, c).Font.ColorIndex = clr1
            Else
                .Cells(r, c).Font.Color = 16777215
            End If
        Else
            .Cells(r, c).Font.ColorIndex = clr3
        End If
    Next c
    Next r

End With
```

For some reason, when I restore the font color, I set an incorrect color.
[image]
If you look at the color of the font in the exemplary cell:
Cell styles / Create cell style, then color: Text1.
If you look at the font color in the target cell:
Cell styles / Create cell style, then color: Beige (rgb 128,128,0).

What am I doing wrong?

**Upd. Working code**

```
Dim oSh As Worksheet
Dim rNg As Range
Set oSh = Sheets("Calculation")
Set rNg = oSh.Range("T_1_1[[Column22]:[Column23]]")
With oSh
    'bring in a variable cell format
    cLr = oSh.ListObjects("T_1_1").ListColumns(20).DataBodyRange.NumberFormat
    If .Cells(2, 25).Value = True Then
        'set "zero" formatting
        rNg.NumberFormat = ";;;"
    Else
        'apply formatting from sample
        rNg.NumberFormat = cLr
    End If
End With
```

Comment: I just added some example code to examine DisplayFormat colors resulting from a table style or conditional formatting.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

**How to make cell content "unvisible" by NumberFormat ;;;**

To hide a cell's content, I suggest not to change colors.
Instead store the original `Range.NumberFormat` and set it to `Range.NumberFormat = ";;;"` which hides positive values, negative values, null values and text, i. e. it hides everything except errors.

**Normal Color and ColorIndex**

You can always read or write the standard color of a cell, e. g.

- `Font.Color`
- `Interior.Color`

The color value is a 3 byte RGB color, can be set by `RGB(red byte, green byte, blue byte)` and be be stored in `Long` variables (4 bytes, representing 0BGR color bytes).

The `ColorIndex` is a value between 1 and 56 only - with varying results, dependig on the color palette of the workbook.

**Displayed Color by DisplayFormat**

The displayed color can be changed by conditional formatting or a table style. It does not change the standard color, but overlays it or is visible instead of the underlying standard color.
You can *read* the overlaying color only, but you can *not set it directly* for each cell:

- `DisplayFormat.Font.Color`
- `DisplayFormat.Interior.Color`

If you change the underlying `.Font.Color`, the visible result depends on the pattern of the overlaying DisplayFormat.

**DisplayFormat by Conditional Formatting (FormatConditions)**

If you want to change the `DisplayFormat` color of a conditional formatting, you can not set it directly on the cell's range itself but within the conditional formatting(s) for that range. Experiment with this:

```
Private Sub DisplayColorByFormatCondition()
    Dim i As Long
    With ActiveSheet.Range("A1")
        Debug.Print "Color Info for " & .Cells.Address
        Debug.Print "Standard Font Color " & .Font.Color & _
                    " is displayed as " & .DisplayFormat.Font.Color; ""
        Debug.Print "Standard Interior Color " & .Interior.Color & _
                    " is displayed as " & .DisplayFormat.Interior.Color
        If .FormatConditions.Count = 0 Then
            Debug.Print "This cell is not part of a FormatCondition."
        Else
            For i = 1 To .FormatConditions.Count
                With .FormatConditions(i)
                    Debug.Print "Condition " & i & " sets Font Color to " & .Font.Color & _
                        "and Interior Color to " & .Interior.Color
                End With
            Next i
        End If
    End With
End Sub
```

**DisplayFormat by Table Style (ListObject.TableStyle)**

If the `DisplayFormat` color results from a table's style, experiment with this:

```
Private Sub DisplayColorByTableStyle()
    Dim lo As ListObject
    Dim i As Long
    With ActiveSheet.Range("A1")
        Debug.Print "Color Info for " & .Cells.Address
        Debug.Print "Standard Font Color " & .Font.Color & _
                    " is displayed as " & .DisplayFormat.Font.Color; ""
        Debug.Print "Standard Interior Color " & .Interior.Color & _
                    " is displayed as " & .DisplayFormat.Interior.Color
        For Each lo In ActiveSheet.ListObjects
            If Not Intersect(lo.Range, .Cells) Is Nothing Then
                Debug.Print "Cell is part of ListObject '" & lo.Name & _
                            "' which uses TableStyle '" & lo.TableStyle & "'"
                If Not Intersect(lo.HeaderRowRange, .Cells) Is Nothing Then
                    Debug.Print "Cell is part of HeaderRowRange. Font color is set to " & _
                                lo.HeaderRowRange.DisplayFormat.Font.Color & _
                                ", Interior color is set to " & _
                                lo.HeaderRowRange.DisplayFormat.Interior.Color
                ElseIf Not Intersect(lo.DataBodyRange, .Cells) Is Nothing Then
                    Debug.Print "Cell is part of DataBodyRange. Font color is set to " & _
                                lo.DataBodyRange.DisplayFormat.Font.Color & _
                                ", Interior color is set to " & _
                                lo.DataBodyRange.DisplayFormat.Interior.Color
                    For i = 1 To lo.ListRows.Count
                        If Not Intersect(lo.ListRows(i).Range, .Cells) Is Nothing Then
                            Debug.Print "Cell is part of ListRows(" & i & "). " & _
                                        "Font color is set to " & _
                                        lo.ListRows(i).Range.DisplayFormat.Font.Color & _
                                        ", Interior color is set to " & _
                                        lo.ListRows(i).Range.DisplayFormat.Interior.Color
                        End If
                    Next i
                End If
            End If
        Next lo
    End With
End Sub
```

Comment: Yes it works! Thanks for the tip.
It is a pity that it was not possible to figure out how to read the formatting of the table.
In the applied express-style, the first line is green, the second unpainted.
What is the property to read information about the background color and font?

Comment: Thanks for the valuable addition!
Now it is clear that in the green line the interior color is set to 14348258. And now I understand how to extract the necessary data.